# She is crying. Active sentence

Tags: passive-voice

She is crying. 
Is it possible to convert this sentence into passive?
How can we change this into passive voice?

Comment: You wrote "I read in different books that we cannot make passive of intransitive verbs".  It appears you already know the answer to your question is 'no'.  What more is there to add?

Answer (score 2):

She is crying.

The verb cry is both transitive and intrsitive. As "cry" is intransitive or  there's no object in the sentence presented, you cannot change the sentence into the passive voice.

Look at the following example in which the cry has been used as a transitive verb:

The mother cried tears of joy when she found her child.

This sentence has an object in it, so it can be changed into the passive voice.  Tears of joy were cried by the mother when she found her child.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> She's overcome with tears.

Comment: Please change this sentence into passive ,

Comment: Cry is intransitive verb. I read in different books that we cannot make passive of intransitive verbs.

Comment: She *is* overcome - isn't this passive voice?  <subject> <to be> <participle II>, no?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't get your "passive" meaning.  Could you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I am trying to ask you how we can make the passive of intransitve verbs?

Comment: In other words, you want to see whether "to cry" can be used in passive voice?  Not necessarily in the same meaning, but "*Her eyes were all cried out*".

Comment: I am talking about intransitive verbs sir.

Comment: Example , I go to school.  Go is intransitive verb. Can we make passive of intransitive verbs?

Comment: As in, "*The school is gone to by me*"?

Comment: Victor , this is mistaken.

Comment: @user124234 Perhaps you should consult a textbook or other source of English grammar. It seems like you don't know what "passive voice" means. Whether that's true or not, it's clear that what you want isn't being communicated adequately. The last sentence I just typed is in passive voice -- the verb phrase "being communicated" is what makes it passive. An active version of that sentence would look something like: "You did not communicate your desires adequately." Telling someone that they have made a mistake doesn't add anything constructive. unless you explain that mistake.

Comment: @CrazyEyes To be more precise, the subordinate clause *that what you want isn't being communicated adequately* is a passive clause.  The matrix clause is active.  This is an example of why it makes more sense to discuss active and passive clauses, not sentences.

Comment: I didn't say someone wrong here. I just said that this is mistaken.  I talked about sentence not victor. I go to school.  Go is intransitive verb. We cannot make its passive form. It's totally wrong.  I read different certified books where it was written that we cannot make passive of intransitive verbs. The word go is also one of them. Don't take me wrong here.  I am just trying to manifest my confusion about my sentence [she is cry].